# Handling "composed classes"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, file, routes

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to know how to manage a resource consisting of a "composed structure". That is, if I have a `User` resource consisting of an `Account` class, a `Profile` class and a `Setting` class, I would like to "refer" to the `User` class to "reach" its child classes (`Account`, `Profile`, `Setting` the "*common\best way*". Since I have a lot of classes in my Model-Controller-View structured application, I would like to "simplify" the file system structure in `app/controllers`, `app/models` and `app/views` folders and properly make the application to work.

What **file** I should create? How should I **routes** `User` resources? What else? Can you link some web resource about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood properly what you are looking for is nested resources.

You will find a description at http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources
and the details about routing in rails 3 at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources.
About where to put the files, just follow the rails conventions. What the user see has nothing to do with where the files are.